# Hybrid app in tablets gives different results when compared to mobile UI

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I wrote a header [as shown here.](http://jsfiddle.net/emxp7thg/)
**`HTML`**

```
<div id="headDiv" role="banner">
            <div id="logoDiv">
                <span id="pageLogo"><img src="images/index_menu_active_phone.png" id="logo"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="pageTitle" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="center-block">
                    <img src="images/cart.png" class="img-rounded" alt="I" width="30" height="30" />
                    <span style="font-family: 'customfont';" id="inheader">Instore</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This works perfectly in mobiles. This is as shown in this screen shot:
[image: img]
However this appears weird in tablets as shown here:
[image: img1]
[image: img2]
I can't even reproduce that error in browser or in jsfiddle. Where is the issue?
I don't want to use media queries.
**EDIT:**
This issue happens in samsung mobiles and tablets, but not in other mobiles like lenovo mobiles, xiomi mobiles...

Comment: try using `sp` instead of `dp`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: u see the size e.g `layout_width=25dp` try it in `sp` instead of `dp`

Comment: **sp**
Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference. it works forr img as well

Comment: Ummm, well.... I've not used `sp` and `dp` in my code. I've used only `px`, `%` and `em`

Comment: tell me one thing that why has android recommended to create different dimmen files for different screen sizes??? because all the screens are not same. SP helps to maintain the size even on other big screens

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But this is a hybrid app where UI is built by bootstrap, functionalities are handled by `javascript` and `java`. So I think that bootstrap should handle aligning of logo image and logo name. But it isn't happening in my case.

Comment: To those whoever downvoted my code: Please elaborate the reason for downvoting

Answer (score 0):

So I was in meeting with my client and she agreed to allow me to use media queries. So I used a media query like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    #searchMenu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5.3%;
        z-index: 10;
        display: none;
        height: 80%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding: 0px;
        min-width: 250px;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    #pageTitle {
        background-color: #FFA500;
        height: 50px;
        padding-top: 1%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-right: 22%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

This fixed it. However I feel that this is temporary solution. Other answers are also welcome